# Nodejs transform image data back to actual image

Tags: node.js, image, http, buffer

My server receives a file from a HTTP request and uploads this file to IBM Cloud Object Storage.

Moreover, the server allows to recover this file. Recovery is triggered by a get http request that should return said file.

It works fine for "basic" data format, such as text files. However, I encounter problems with more complex types such as images and the "reformating".

Image is uploaded to the datastore. The element stored is the buffer itself:

```
req.files[0].buffer
```

When getting the image back from the datastore, how can I transform it back to a readable format for my computer?

The data look like this and it is, on the server, a `string`:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ExpressJS you can do this:

```
const data = req.files[0].buffer;
res.contentType('image/jpeg'); // don't know what type is
res.send(data);
```